# Wait for process with name to spawn in Bash

Tags: bash, process

I want to write a Bash script that runs in a background, waiting for a command to spawn.

Suppose I ran script.sh which waits for `ls`. After I run `ls`, it should trigger actions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pgrep` to create a while loop like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Wait for particular process to run
while ! pgrep "process-name " > /dev/null; do

    # Set optional delay
    sleep .1

done

# Do something when the process has started
your-commands-here
```

You need to adjust the delay, so that it "catches" the process you run. This of course works best if it should detect a service that doesn't stop again, but this will work for any command that takes longer time to finish than the delay you have set (`ls` is a bad example, since it only takes milliseconds to finish the process).

Also see [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410062/bash-check-that-process-has-started-before-continuing-script) on Unix and Linux.